# how to use in data from oracle to calculate on C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, calculated-field

I have a table in Oracle with lots of data. In the structure of:

```
code_value    date_value     value
1             20/07/2017      10.5
1             19/07/2017      11.6
2             20/07/2017      1000.22
2             18/07/2017      1700.44
```

I have another table that defines a test for this data:
Whose structure is as follows:

```
code_value      check_rule      check_period    connection_rule
1                16%            w               or
1                30%            m               or
1                50%            y               or
2                130%           w               and
2                110%           6m              and
```

*p.s. "check_period": w - for week, m - for month, y - for year.

** p.s. I'm still debating if split this column into two columns: one for the amount of time and one for the time type (ex: 6, m).

I would like to take the test table and run it on the table with the data, on C#.
but I don't know how to start to do it:
How do I take a value from a table and use it to calculate?
for example:
if I will take the first line, with 16% check_rule, and I will do:
var a = check_rule[0];
How to check whether the increase was 16% per week?
In the same way how to use OR on "connection_rule"?

I'm really hope that my question clear enough.

Thank U!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Your Connection string");
conn.Open();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t inner join TABLE2 t1 on t.code_value = t1.code_value"
);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = conn;

using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
//loop through table's rows/columns
var myVal = ParseToDouble(dt.Rows["value"].ToString());
var checkRule = ParseToDouble(dt.Rows["check_rule"].ToString());

if(myVal < checkRule)
   doSomething();


public double ParseToDouble(string s)
{
    return decimal.Parse( s.TrimEnd('%') ) / 100M;
}
```

Comment: Thank U, But, I know how to connect and how to write code. but I dont know how to replace the dt.Rows["check_rule"].toString() to something that I calculate with it. to do "value" from first table >=  check_rule.

Comment: You mean like `var num = decimal.Parse( a.TrimEnd( new char[] { '%', ' ' } ) ) / 100M;`