# Logic expression - Oracle & C#

Tags: c#, oracle, expression, logical-operators

I have a table in Oracle with lots of data. In the structure of:

```
code_value    date_value     value
1             20/07/2017      10.5%
1             19/07/2017      11.6%
2             20/07/2017      1000.22%
2             18/07/2017      1700.44%
```

I have another table that defines a logic expression for this data: Whose structure is as follows:

```
code_value      check_rule    connection_rule
1                <16%              or
1                >30%              or
1                ==50%             or
2                >130%             and
2                <110%             and
```

I would like to take the second table and run it on the table with the data, on C#.
How do I build a logic expression by this table, on C#?
like: "if code_value <16% or code_value >30% or code_value ==50%".
Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the rules limited to `<`, `>` and `==`?

Comment: yes. It is limited to that.

Comment: Are you checking to see if 1700.44 is  `< 110%`?  That doesn't even make sense. 110% of what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use in data from oracle to calculate on C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220498/how-to-use-in-data-from-oracle-to-calculate-on-c)

Comment: it's not duplicate. there it's without logic expression...

Comment: there is only to extract numbers

Comment: you right. mathguy. the value in the first table is also in percentage. I corrected it. but I can save the data without percentage, if it's matter.

Comment: mathguy , I don't understand why you flag it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel adventurous, you can do it in a single SQL Query and then just fetch the result in your C# application and display it.

```
--CREATION OF THE TEST TABLES WITH DATA
create table test_data  ( data_id number, code_value number, date_value date, value varchar2(30) );
create table test_rules ( code_value number, check_rule varchar2(10), connection_rule varchar2(3));

insert into test_data values (1,1,to_date('20/07/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),'10.5%');
insert into test_data values (2,1,to_date('19/07/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),'11.6%');
insert into test_data values (3,2,to_date('20/07/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),'1000.22%');
insert into test_data values (4,2,to_date('18/07/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),'1700.44%');

insert into test_rules values (1,'<16%','or');
insert into test_rules values (1,'>30%','or');
insert into test_rules values (1,'==50%','or');
insert into test_rules values (2,'>130%','and');
insert into test_rules values (2,'<110%','and');

--THE QUERY
with 
connection_rules as ( select code_value, ' '||max(connection_rule)||' ' connection_rule  from test_rules group by code_value),
rules            as ( select code_value, substr(check_rule,0,1)||regexp_replace(check_rule,'[^0-9.]','')/100 as rule from test_rules),
checks           as ( select test_data.data_id, test_data.code_value, test_data.date_value, test_data.value, regexp_replace(test_data.value,'[^0-9.]','')/100 || ' ' || rules.rule as check1 from test_data join rules on test_data.code_value=rules.code_value),
expressions      as ( select checks.data_id, checks.date_value, checks.value, LISTAGG(checks.check1,connection_rules.connection_rule) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 1 ) as condition FROM checks JOIN connection_rules on checks.code_value =connection_rules.code_value group by checks.data_id, checks.code_value, connection_rules.connection_rule, checks.date_value, checks.value )
select expressions.data_id, expressions.date_value, expressions.value, substr(expressions.condition,0,50) condition, substr(xmlquery(expressions.condition returning content),0,10) as result  from expressions ;
```

result :

```
DATA_ID DATE_VALUE  VALUE       CONDITION                           RESULT
1       20-JUL-17   10.5%       .105 <.16 or .105 =.5 or .105 >.3   true
2       19-JUL-17   11.6%       .116 <.16 or .116 =.5 or .116 >.3   true
3       20-JUL-17   1000.22%    10.0022 <1.1 and 10.0022 >1.3       false
4       18-JUL-17   1700.44%    17.0044 <1.1 and 17.0044 >1.3       false
```

it works as long as you dont have rules which mix AND and OR conditions. Anyway your data structure would not allow it because you would have to have a notion of priority if you want to mix

Comment: Of course, I would not advise to run it like that on a large dataset. You might receive the visit of your favourite DBA with that particular look on his face meaning : "Dude ... Seriously?". But it works and gives you an idea on how to do it